# Highchart with straight lines and empty circle bullet

Tags: highcharts

I need create a highchart like this image

[image]
so what options i should set for chart?
for straight lines between markers and empty circle for markers and have dotted lines in background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a step line, instead of a regular line, use [series.step](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.step).  To change the markers use [series.marker](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker).  And to make the grid lines dashed, use [yAxis.gridLineDashStyle](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineDashStyle).  The Highcharts API reference is excellent and has lots of examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbo9jag5/6/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  },
  yAxis: {
     gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 1, 9],
    step: 'right',
    name: 'Right',
    marker: {
      fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
      radius: 5,
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: null // inherit from series
    }
  }]

});
```